# How to change an image inside an Adobe Edge animation from externtal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

I have an adobe edge animation inside my html page, I just want to change an image inside that animation from my html page with another photo (mainly an image the user will upload)

notice that this photo is duplicated inside of the animation so I have to change them all (I added the same class to all of them in attempt to use jQuery in this thing but I failed)

Comment: Maybe edit your question after reading [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @sandeeps I found the solution along time ago and I couldn't post it because of my low score! now I kinda lost the project and I can't post the answer to help others!